# Calculate weeks between more than one date entry in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So im developing a system for leopard gecko breeding and need to determine the average weeks between clutches being laid in order to roughly estimate when the next clutch of eggs will be laid. Here is my sql i am using to select all the entries for a gecko's ID

```
SELECT * 
FROM clutches 
WHERE clutch_breeding_pair = 2 ORDER BY clutch_laid_date DESC
```

EDIT - Here's my SQL query

```
$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM clutches WHERE clutch_breeding_pair = '$breedingPairID' ORDER BY clutch_laid_date DESC");
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

and here is a link to my sql table and query working online - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb1c1e/4

I am not very familiar with sql datediff etc so have no idea what the best practice is for this. Apologies if this question isn't quite in depth enough, i literally don't fully know what to search for to see if there have been similar questions before.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This will not be straightforward. You might have to use stored procedure or in your server side code you will have to process the data to get date differences and do something with it.

Comment: I have tried to do it so that it gets the last 2 and compares those dates to get the weeks but i feel it's going to be a massive headache trying to get this to work

Comment: Which server side language you using?

Comment: PHP, says in the title ;)

Comment: Do you want the average time between clutches for each breeding pair? Should be possible using sql only. I'll give it a try.

Comment: That's exactly it. If gecko 2 has say 4 clutches, i'd like to know her average time between the clutches in order to roughly predict when the next one is

Comment: See my answer. It does that for all clutch pair groups.

Comment: Do you want the avg weeks per clutch pair group? or across all clutch pair groups?

Comment: Sorry Ron, per breeding pair, so pair 1, 2, 3 seperately if you get what i mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will average the weeks between each clutch_laid_date in each clutch_pair group:

```
SELECT c.clutch_breeding_pair,
  ifnull(AVG(datediff(c.next_clutch_laid_date,c.clutch_laid_date)/7),0) average_weeks
FROM (
    SELECT c1.clutch_breeding_pair,
      c1.clutch_laid_date,
      min(c2.clutch_laid_date) next_clutch_laid_date
    FROM clutches c1
      left join clutches c2
        on c2.clutch_laid_date > c1.clutch_laid_date
        and c2.clutch_breeding_pair = c1.clutch_breeding_pair
    WHERE c1.clutch_breeding_pair = 2
    GROUP BY
      c1.clutch_breeding_pair,
      c1.clutch_laid_date
    ) c
GROUP BY
  c.clutch_breeding_pair
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/daae57/2

Comment: Does this work for each clutch pair id? or is it calculating all of them? As i'd like to run it with different clutch pairs

Comment: Updated for each clutch_pair_id.

Comment: Sorry for sounding like an utter noob here, but is there a way i can set which breeding pair id i look up?

Comment: Sure, just add a `Where clutch_breeding_pair = ` after the join. I'll update it.

Comment: Thanks mate, really do appreciate this :)

Comment: This looks like an absolute winner, you okay to stick around while i test for a couple of mins?

Comment: This works great, just one minor thing. If a gecko has only laid one clutch, there will obviously be no average to calculate. Is there something we can do to return maybe a 0 if there's no average to be made?

Comment: ok, updated. The left join will produce a null for the `next_clutch_laid_date` and the `ifnull` will put a zero in for the null value.

Comment: You I removed one of the test records to test this. It is clutch_breeding_pair 3.

Comment: Absolutely freaking wonderful. Thank you SO much for that! I really am super grateful for all your help Ron, thank you dude!

Answer (score 1):

This query returns the average weeks between all `clutch_laid_date` for each `clutch_breeding_pair` group.

**It is absolutely possible to achieve this without joins or subqueries. And I highly recommend doing so. Otherwise it's a hell of a performance waste.**

```
SELECT clutch_breeding_pair,
    truncate((datediff(max(clutch_laid_date), min(clutch_laid_date)) /
      IF (count(*) > 1, count(*) - 1, 1) / 7), 4) AS average_weeks
  FROM clutches
-- WHERE clutch_breeding_pair = 2 -- filter by clutch_breeding_pair
  GROUP BY clutch_breeding_pair
-- HAVING average_weeks > 0; -- remove 0 value rows
```

DEMO @ **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fe75/3)**

You can uncomment the following line to filter your results by `clutch_breeding_pair`:

```
WHERE clutch_breeding_pair = 2 -- filter by clutch_breeding_pair
```

And / or you can uncomment this line to remove 0 values from the resultset:

```
HAVING average_weeks > 0; -- remove 0 value rows
```

Comment: But what if there are more than two clutch_laid_date values for a breeding group?

Comment: @RonSmith - I added an additional date to my fiddle. Works fine. What do you mean, exactly? I am confused :-)

Comment: @AndyHolmes - I updated my answer. It will lead to a massive performance boost that you'll appreciate when your table size increases.